# Send Multiple Device Tokens to Parse through CURL

Tags: ios, curl, parse-platform

I am using Parse to send push notifications to my iOS app users. This works well, but the way I have constructed it leads to a page timeout when sending the push to many users.

The code below is in a while loop that sends the data one device token at a time through curl. How would I reconstruct the payload so that I can push a single JSON array that will contain all of the device tokens etc... Any ideas?

**My While Loop:**

```
$target_device = $row['device_token'];

$push_payload = json_encode(array(
        "where" => array(
                "deviceToken" => $target_device,
        ),
        "data" => array(
                "alert" => "$message"
        )
));

$rest = curl_init();
curl_setopt($rest,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($rest,CURLOPT_PORT,443);
curl_setopt($rest,CURLOPT_POST,1);
curl_setopt($rest,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$push_payload);
curl_setopt($rest,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,
        array("X-Parse-Application-Id: " . $appId,
                "X-Parse-REST-API-Key: " . $restKey,
                "Content-Type: application/json"));

$response = curl_exec($rest);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `set_time_limit(0);` so that your page doesn't get the timeout.

You are also try using the `curl_milti` for parallel curl requests. But it will not help you to avoid the timeout if the requests are too many.